# Pure CSS-animation on href-link (click)

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have a problem with my animation (fadin).
The goal should be that the animation is only triggered when I click "ccc" in the menu.

Currently the animation starts when I reload the page. I have tried "target", "focus" etc. I having problem seeing the solution.

Further question: can I create the effect without keyframe? I tried it with transition/opacity. Without success. Does anyone have an idea?

I am looking for a pure CSS-Solution.

thx

```css
:root {
    --colorPrimary: #A2C7E2;
    --colorSecondary: #fff;
    --colorHover: #104068;
    --colorHoverBG: #7398C5;
    --colorParagraph: #8b8b8b;
}
body,html{
    height: 100vh;
}

body{
    margin: 0;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: 
        "header"
        "main"
        "footer";
}

header{
    grid-area: header;
    background-color: #545658;
}

main{
    grid-area: main;
    overflow: hidden;
}

nav{
    grid-area: footer;
    background-color: #acb0b4;
}

nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4,auto);
    padding: 0px;
    justify-items: center;
}

ul li a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav a:hover { background: #691717; }
/* PLACEHOLDER ICONS */

/* nav i {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-style: normal;
} */


.a,
.b,
.c,
.d{
    height: 100vh;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4,auto);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(4,auto);
}

.b,
.d{
    background-color: var(--colorSecondary);
}

.a,
.c{
    background-color: var(--colorPrimary);
}


main section{
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
}

.c{
    grid-gap:1rem;
    grid-template-areas: 
        "box1 box1 box1 box1"
        "box2 box2 box3 box3"
        "box4 box4 box3 box3"
        "box4 box4 box5 box5";
}

.c .grid-box{
    background: #ff6e48;
    transition: all 250ms;
    box-shadow: 0 0.1rem 0.3rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
    animation: fadein 1s ease-out normal backwards;
  
 
  
}



.c .grid-box:hover{
    z-index: 2;
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: 0 1.5rem 2.8rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15),
    0 1rem 1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    transform: translate(0, -0.5rem) scale(1.01); 
}



.c .element1{
    grid-area: box1;
    animation-delay: 0;
}

.c .element2{
    grid-area: box2;
    animation-delay: 100ms;
}

.c .element3{
    grid-area: box3;
    animation-delay: 200ms;
}

.c .element4{
    grid-area: box4;
    animation-delay: 300ms;
}

.c .element5{
    grid-area: box5;
    animation-delay: 400ms;
}


@keyframes fadein {
    0% {
      transform: scale(0);
    }
    70% {
      transform: scale(1.05);
    }
    100% {
      transform: scale(1);
    }
  }


 



a[ id= "A" ]:target ~ main section {
    -webkit-transform: translateY( 0vh);
    transform: translateY( 0vh );
}

a[ id= "B" ]:target ~ main section {
    -webkit-transform: translateY( -100vh );
    transform: translateY( -100vh );
}
a[ id= "C" ]:target ~ main section {
    -webkit-transform: translateY( -200vh );
    transform: translateY( -200vh );
    
}

a[ id= "D" ]:target ~ main section {
    -webkit-transform: translateY( -300vh );
    transform: translateY( -300vh );
}
```

```html
<body>
 <a id="A"></a>
 <a id="B"></a>
 <a id="C"></a>
 <a id="D"></a>

      <header></header>

      <nav>
        <!-- <div class="navigation"> -->
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#A">aaa</a></li>
            <li><a href="#B">bbb</a></li>
            <li><a href="#C">ccc</a></li>
            <li><a href="#D">ddd</a></li>
          </ul>
        <!-- </div> -->
      </nav>

      <main>
        <section class="a"id="A"></section>
        <section class="b"id="B"></section>
        <section class="c"id="C">
          <div class="element1 grid-box">1</div>
          <div class="element2 grid-box">2</div>
          <div class="element3 grid-box">3</div>
          <div class="element4 grid-box">4</div>
          <div class="element5 grid-box">5</div>
        </section>
        <section class="d"id="D"></section>
      </main>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: _"Currently the animation starts when I reload the page"_ - of course it does, because you are applying it to the elements without any further "condition". _" have tried "target", "focus" etc."_ - the target pseudo class would be the way to go here - but you need to apply it to the correct element. When you clicked that link, `#C` will show in the address bar, and it will target the element with the ID `C`.

Comment: And IDs _must_ be unique within an HTML document, so remove the duplication you currently have there first of all.

Answer (score 1):

I've radically simplified your setup above (for demonstration purposes) but here is a straightforward **CSS-only** example which combines:

1. **CSS transitions** (ie. rather than `@keyframes`)
2. use of the `:target` pseudo-selector to activate the `transition`

---

**Working Example:**

```css
main {
 position: relative;
 float: right;
 width: 50%;
}

section {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 0;
}

section p {
  margin: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.6s ease-out;
}

section:target p {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<main>
<section id="a"><p>Section A targeted</p></section>
<section id="b"><p>Section B targeted</p></section>
<section id="c"><p>Section C targeted</p></section>
<section id="d"><p>Section D targeted</p></section>
</main>

<nav>
<ul>
<li><a href="#a">Target Section A</a></li>
<li><a href="#b">Target Section B</a></li>
<li><a href="#c">Target Section C</a></li>
<li><a href="#d">Target Section D</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```